# "Product Type is invalid or not supported in rows" error when importing append data into Magento.

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I'm attempting to import appended product data into Magento and I'm receiving the error message "Product Type is invalid or not supported in rows:".

My data is only 2 columns: **sku**, and an attribute called **rw_google_base_product_type**

That's it. Any idea why I would be receiving this error? Seems like it should be straight forward; append attribute values to skus.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?